# Monopoly game recreating deck after cards are picked

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Initial**

```
cardCount = { chest: [0], chance: [0]};
```

**Create Cards**

```
function createCards() {
    cards = {

        chance: [{
            title: 'Advance to go',
            type: 'move',
            position: 40
        }, {
            title: "Advance to London",
            type: "move",
            position: 39
        }, {
            title: "Your ass is going to jail",
            type: "move",
            position: 10
        }, {
            title: "Advance to Rome",
            type: "move",
            position: 24
        }, {
            title: "Advance to Charles de Gaulle",
            type: "move",
            position: 15
        }, {
            title: "Advance to Amsterdam",
            type: "move",
            position: 11
        }, {
            title: "Go back 3 spaces",
            type: "movex",
            position: -3
        }, {
            title: "No drink and driving mate1",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 20
        }, {
            title: "Get out of Jail free card",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 150
        }, {
            title: "Pay school fees",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 150
        }, {
            title: "Speeding fine",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 150
        }, {
            title: "Bank pays you dividend",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 40
        }, {
            title: "You have won the competition",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 200
        }, {
            title: "Your building loan matures",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 200
        }, {
            title: "You are assessed for street repairs $40 per house $115 per hotel",
            type: "billx"
        }, {
            title: "House repairs $25 per house $100 per hotel",
            type: "billx"
        }],
        chest: [{
            title: "Advance to go",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 40,
            bonus: 200
        }, {
            title: "Advance to Cairo",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 1
        }, {
            title: "Go to Jail",
            type: "move",
            newposition: 10
        }, {
            title: "Pay hospital fees",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 100
        }, {
            title: "Pay doctor fees",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 50
        }, {
            title: "Pay insurance premium",
            type: "bill",
            bill: 50
        }, {
            title: "Bank error. Collect $200",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 200
        }, {
            title: "Annuity matures. Collect $100",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 100
        }, {
            title: "You inherit $100",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 100
        }, {
            title: "From sale of stock you get $50",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 50
        }, {
            title: "Preference shares: $25",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 25
        }, {
            title: "You have won second prize in a beauty contest. Collect $10.",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 10
        }, {
            title: "It is your birthday. Collect $10.",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 10
        }, {
            title: "You win the lottery. Collect $10",
            type: "bonus",
            bonus: 10
        }]
    };
}
```

**Pick**

```
function pickCard(type) {

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cards[type].length));
    var title = cards[type][x].title;

    cardCount[type][0]++;
    cards[type].splice(x, 1);

    if (cards[type].length === 0) {

        cardCount[type][0] = 0;
        createCards(); // this is the problem code line
    }
}
```

Ok guys I need a little tweak. There are 2 cards drawn and I keep a counter for them. Whenever a deck has been fully picked, I recreate the cards `createCards` the problem is in doing so I also recreate the other deck, because `createCards` creates 2 decks `chance` and `chest`. How should I tweak my code without creating a different object for the 2 decks?

Answer (score 0):

I assume cards is a global or at least you do "var cards" somewhere in a larger scope?

First time:

```
createCards ()
```

From pickCard:

```
createCards ([type])
```

Modify createCards as follows:

```
function createCards (options) {
 if (typeof options == "undefined") {options = ['chance', 'chest']; cards = {}}
 if (options.indexOf('chance') != -1) {
  cards.chance = {...}
 }
 if (options.indexOf('chest') != -1) {
  cards.chest = {...}
 }
}
```

PS: it would make things more interesting if you randomized the order in the createCards function.

Comment: Yes cards is a global. Ok when you call `createCards` from pickCard you pass `type`. Up to there I am with you. Then in createCards you start with an if statement...you check if it is undefined...what are you doing in case it is undefined sorry?

Comment: This code doesn't pass `type`, it passes `[type]`: `type` in an array. If no options are given, it sets the options to a `['chance', 'chest']` array and `cards` to an empty object (`{}`).

Comment: Ok you lost me completely. I will look at your code in the morning, its definitely not sinking in right now. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any particular part that you would like me to elaborate on?

Comment: [link] (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39831/monopoly-game-cards)[/link] I have restructured my code as per adviced there. I use a  shuffle function instead.